# Use mapping function to render buttons and how can each button works independently in React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I have 3 sets of button here, I want to disable 'cancel button' after clicking once, and vice versa.

However when I disable the 'cancel' button from first set, the 'cancel'  button from other sets will be disabled too.

In this case I want to disable the 'cancel' button from first set only.

How do I solve this issue or is there any approach to do so.

any help and suggestions will be appreciated

note ** I am using Mapping function to render the buttons

my client side:

```
 function App() {
  const [taskNumber, setTaskNumber] = useState('')
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true)
  const onChange = (e) => {
  setTaskNumber(e.target.value)
  }

  const onClick = () => {
   console.log('world')
   setDisable(!disable)
  }


  const button = (index) => {
return (
  < div >
    <button onClick={() => onClick()} disabled={!disable}>hello</button>
    <button onClick={() => onClick()} disabled={disable}>cancel</button>
  </div >
)
}

  let items = []

 for (let i = 0; i < taskNumber; i++) {
   // items.push(button(i))
   items.push(i)
  }


   <Form>

    <Form.Group as={Col}>
      <Form.Label>Number of Task</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="number"
        min='1'
        placeholder="Enter number of task"
        name='taskNumber'
        value={taskNumber}
        onChange={onChange}
      />


    </Form.Group>
  </Form>
  {items.map((number) => {
    return button(number)
  })}
```

My React user Interface

[image]

Comment: add to the button component a disabled or not prop, as it is right now it's using the "global" one and every button you use follow that

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate more about it cuz I am new in React. or you can give me an example. thank you.

Comment: basically `const button = ({index, disabled}) => {` then, when you map, you pass both values to it: `return button({index: number, disabled: true/false})`

Comment: @jackson see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you can use an array in `disable` to control which element is enabled.

*** edit ***

I didn't have access to the form components you were using so I just made a more basic example for you to refer to.  See my codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-fast-0zneb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but it does not work. Did I miss out something?